# Spectrum of a discrete-time observability Gramian from system matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, linear-control

Suppose that $A$ is an **asymmetric** matrix that has all eigenvalues inside the unit circle. Let $Q$ be a symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix.

Let $W=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (A’)^t Q A^t$ a discrete time observability Gramian, or the solution to the discrete Lyapunov equation $A'WA-W+Q=0$.

If we know the spectrum of $A$ and $Q$, can we say anything about the spectrum of $W$?

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. Care sharing more details?

Comment: @KBS It would be helpful, for example, to have an upper bound on the largest eigenvalue, or to have any sort of bounds that relate the eigenvectors of W to the eigenvectors of A and Q.

Comment: @phil if one considers both the eigenvalues and their associated eigenvectors of A and Q then one knows A and Q (assuming the Jordan normal form of A only has Jordan blocks of size one) and thus one can calculate W.

Comment: Your discrete Lyapunov equation looks wrong, I believe it should A' on the left instead on on the right from W. Or are you using a different definition for the observability Gramian, in which case your summation expression does not match.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thank you, I had the $A'$ switched

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I know that it can be calculated. I am just wondering if there is a way to express the eigenvalues or eigenvectors of $W$ in terms of the spectra of its composite matrices $A$ and $Q$. Just to clarify, I know both $A$ and $Q$

Comment: No, unless in very particular cases (e.g/ $A$ and $Q$ commute) you will not be able to infer what you want. The reason is that eigenvalues do not behave very nicely under summation and product operations.

Comment: If $\|A\|_2<1$ (this guarantees that $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (A’)^t Q A^t$ converges), we have $$\|Q\|_2=\|W-A'WA\|_2\ge\|W\|_2-\|A'\|_2\|W\|_2\|A\|_2=(1-\|A\|_2^2)\|W\|_2$$ and hence $\rho(W)\le\frac{\rho(Q)}{1-\|A\|_2^2}$.